# bootstrap 3 center content vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i know this has been asked many times before, but i can't seem to get it to work. How do i center content vertically using bootstrap 3? My site is responsive too. here is what i have so far

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <img src="bla.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 vcenter">
                            content to be aligned center vertically to image bla.png
                    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is

```
.row [class*="col-md-"].vcenter, .vcenter {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

here is the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/](http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/1/)

Comment: Put it into a fiddle for us

Comment: You want it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/2/ ?

Comment: @DanielLisik no, the text should be aligned center vertically to th image on it's left

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/3/ ?

Comment: @DanielLisik it still shows below it http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/4/

Comment: @user2636556 that's because the image is not responsive, if you stretch out the Result frame the text and image *will* be beside each other.

Comment: @user2636556 Have you tried to use bootstraps grid offset to accomplish this? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

HTML: 
   
        
            
        
        
            
                      centered text

CSS:

```
.row [class*="col-md-"].vcenter, .vcenter {
    display:table !important;
    height:300px;
}

.vcenter .content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLQes/5/)